# Probability coin toss-> probability tends to 1

Tags: probability

Maybe someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

A fair coin is tossed repeatedly.Show that the probability of a head turning up for the first time after n tosses tends to one.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the problem correctly?  The way I interpret it is "the probability that the $n$'th flip is a head and all previous flips are tails" and this probability certainly does not approach 1, but rather zero...

Comment: Yes, the problem was given by my professor. That´s why I´am also a little bit confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the probability that no head have appeared after $n$ throws is the same as the probability that $n$ tails appeared which is $\frac{1}{2^n}$. Hence your probability equals
$$
Pr[\text{no head have appeared after} n \text{ throws}] = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
I let you conclude.